# Create table with mean of columns from two different files

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two files, one named `mint_04_export` and one named `maxt_04_export`:

`dput(mint_04_export)`

```
structure(list(CodeNidif = c("A08B08_200801", "A08E31_201501",
"A09A03_200901", "A12B01_201301"), Altitude = c(296, 278, 301,
296), 091-095 = c(-9.82, -9.73, -9.84, -9.82), 096-100 = c(-9.78,
-9.75, -9.82, -9.78), 101-105 = c(-6.96, -6.9, -6.99, -6.96
)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput(maxt_04_export)`

```
structure(list(CodeNidif = c("A08B08_200801", "A08E31_201501",
"A09A03_200901", "A12B01_201301"), Altitude = c(296, 278, 301,
296), 091-095 = c(1.71, 1.78, 1.68, 1.71), 096-100 = c(1.17,
1.26, 1.13, 1.17), 101-105 = c(5.52, 5.59, 5.48, 5.52)), row.names = c(NA,
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a table where I would keep the first columns : `CodeNifid` and `Altitude`, but would like to get the mean of the columns of the same name. E.g.
the value of 091-095 of the row of A08B08_200801 from both both tables mint_04_export and maxt_04_export.

I am not able to do this, here is what I tried (by joining the two files together):

```
combin_04<-mint_04 %>%
  left_join(maxt_04, by='CodeNidif')

moyt_04<-mint_04 %>%
  left_join(maxt_04, by='CodeNidif') %>%
  group_by(CodeNidif) %>%
  summarize(moyt=mean(`091-095.x`,`091-095.y`))
```

I am on Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_4_0

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding the two frames and dividing by two?

```
bind_cols(
  select(mint_04_export,1,2),
  (mint_04_export[, -c(1,2)] + maxt_04_export[, -c(1,2)])/2
)
```

Another option is to row bind the frames, and take using `group_by()` and `summarize(across())`:

```
bind_rows(mint_04_export,maxt_04_export) %>%
  group_by(CodeNidif, Altitude) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
```

Output (under either approach):

```
      CodeNidif Altitude 091-095 096-100 101-105
1 A08B08_200801      296  -4.055  -4.305  -0.720
2 A08E31_201501      278  -3.975  -4.245  -0.655
3 A09A03_200901      301  -4.080  -4.345  -0.755
4 A12B01_201301      296  -4.055  -4.305  -0.720
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

# make them a data.table
setDT(combin_04)
setDT(moyt_04)

rbindlist(list(combin_04, moyt_04))[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(CodeNidif, Altitude)]
```

**results**

```
       CodeNidif Altitude 091-095 096-100 101-105
1: A08B08_200801      296  -4.055  -4.305  -0.720
2: A08E31_201501      278  -3.975  -4.245  -0.655
3: A09A03_200901      301  -4.080  -4.345  -0.755
4: A12B01_201301      296  -4.055  -4.305  -0.720
```